# Default value DataSource in ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a ComboBox, and that is how I fill the data in it:

```
SectorCollection sectorCollection = sectorController.SearchAll();

comboSector.DataSource = null;

comboSector.DataSource = sectorCollection;
comboSector.DisplayMember = "titleSector";
comboSector.ValueMember = "idSector";
```

What I want is to set a pre data, like a text in the combobox without a value.
Like "Select a Sector." So the user can knows what does he is selecting.

Comment: It is winform or asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a WinForm combobox then you should code something like this

```
sectorCollection.Insert(0, new Sector() {idSector=0, titleSector="Select a sector"})

comboSector.DataSource = sectorCollection;
comboSector.DisplayMember = "titleSector";
comboSector.ValueMember = "idSector";
```

You need to add the selection prompt as a new `Sector` instance added to the collection and then bind the collection to your combobox. Of course this could be a problem if you use the collection for other purposes a part from the combo display

Comment: @ghostJago what's missing to be totally helpful?

Comment: @Steve nothing in your answer.  It just gave me inspiration to solve my problem.  The Insert method was what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Just insert a new item at index 0 as the default after your `DataBind()`:

```
comboSector.DataSource = sectorCollection;
comboSector.DisplayMember = "titleSector";
comboSector.ValueMember = "idSector";
comboSector.DataBind();

comboSector.Items.Insert(0, "Select a Sector.");
```

If this is `WinForms` (you haven't said) then you would add a new item to the `sectorCollection` at index 0 before assigning to the combobox. All other code remains the same:

```
sectorCollection.Insert(0, new Sector() { idSector = 0, titleSector = "Select a sector." });
```

Comment: But there is no method "DataBind" in a ComboBox, I understood that I have to Bind the Data into the combobox so I can change it. But how can I do that?

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment explaining how this answer can be improved.

Answer (score 4):

I think rather than adding a dummy item, which will alway be on the top of the list, just set SelectedIndex to -1 and add your text:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBox1.Text = "Select an item";
```