# not able to set default value in combobox : C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I was trying to add a default value ("--select item--") in existing ComboBox which is getting filled by Database table. Here is my code.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = .\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog= Student; Trusted_Connection = True");
string query = "select Id, Name from abc1";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
conn.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

dt.Load(reader);

comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Everything is working fine in above code and I'm getting CB filled with desired values.

Now when I try to insert default value using below, then it is throwing an error. This way was [tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342670/setting-default-item-in-combo-box)

```
comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select"); //this is throwing an error
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

[image]

I further [explored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613885/default-value-datasource-in-combobox-c-sharp) below code to add default item.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBox1.Text = "Select an item";
```

This added an item as desired, but on any event, CB loses this value. After `SelectIndexChanged` event, I lose this value. So this **cannot** be my solution.

Any advise?

Comment: This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5134229/2572551

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather not *intefere* into binding, but *edit* SQL instead:

```
string query = 
  @"select 0 as Id,        -- or whatever default value you want
           'select' as Name, 
           0, 
     union all
    -- your original query here
    select Id, 
           Name,
           1  
      from abc1
    -- to have default value on the top
  order by 3 asc";
```

Comment: This is a tricky solution.. I thought of it, but let me explore solution on c# side..

Answer (score 0):

Insert's second parameter is expecting a `ComboBox.ObjectCollection` object.
Try doing this:

Having a class

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

And using:

```
// This could be inline, but for simplicity step by step...
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "Item text1";
item.Value = 12;

comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
//or
comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, item);
```

Comment: Nopes, no error.. Executed successfully. But didn't get the item as desired... CB is showing value that were in the DB only..

Answer (score 0):

You can add programmatically the item to the datatable

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["id"] = "0";
dr["name"] = "Select";

dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
```

then you can set the datasource

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a suggestion text to your user, the "EDIT" part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064216/3413552) may help (can only work if your `ComboBox`'s `DropDownStyle` is not set to `DropDownList`).

But if you really want some "Select" item in your `ComboBox`, try this:

```
    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //load your datatable here
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new { ID = 0, Name = "Select" });
        foreach (DataRow a in dt.Rows)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new { ID = a["ID"], Name = a["Name"] });
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBox1.DropDown += new EventHandler(comboBox1_DropDown);
        comboBox1.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(comboBox1_DropDownClosed);
    }

    void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(new { ID = 0, Name = "Select" }))
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, new { ID = 0, Name = "Select" });
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Items.Contains(new { ID = 0, Name = "Select" }))
            comboBox1.Items.Remove(new { ID = 0, Name = "Select" });
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this so lengthy sol?

Comment: Yep, if you don't mind having the "Select" item shown in dropdownlist, just replace `comboBox1.DataSource = dt;` with `comboBox1.Items.Add(new { ID = 0, Name = "Select" }); foreach (DataRow a in dt.Rows) comboBox1.Items.Add(new { ID = a["ID"], Name = a["Name"] });`

Comment: Or just Add a new row on top of your datatable before set the ComboBox's DataSource as @user3401335 suggest.